# How to Pass Full-Qualified Excel Sheet Name to VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA, i'd like to refer to sheets in different workbooks by string-name.

The following return errors:

```
Set oSht = Worksheets( "'[My Book.xlsb]MySheet'" )
Set oSht = Evaluate( "'[My Book.xlsb]MySheet'" )
```

I know i can say:

```
Set oSht = Workbooks("My Book.xlsb").Sheets("MySheet")
```

but seeking a method which does not use the Workbooks collection.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) of a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
Set oSht = Range("'[My Book.xlsb]MySheet'!A1").Parent
```

This works because the .Range object accepts and interprets a wider variety of text describing a specific cell. If you drill down to an individual cell and use that to call the .parent, you can achieve the worksheet reference.

If there is a chance that My Book.xlsb may be closed, use the equivalent of the [Workbook.FullName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834975.aspx), not just the [Workbook.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx).